# How to get SAML response through Play PAC4J

Tags: java, playframework, wso2-identity-server

I am using Play framework and PAC4J to authenticate WSO2 via SAML SSO. I need SAMLResponse back to generate cookie and access WSO2 APIs. How to get SAML response from PAC4j?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take alook at [play-pac4j-scala-demo](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-scala-demo)? There is an example showing the creation of a JWT token using the ProfileManager.